# SSMS save results with Query plan to analyze later

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm currently analysing a performance issue with some dmv's that return execution performance information (max_worker_time, exec_count, etc) along with the execution plan text and even de query plan xml. Like this:

[image: ssms result with text and query plan]

I can easily extract data from an ssms query result to excel, csv, or text file.

Problem is, the text and query_plan columns contains commands and spaces. I can't export it in an useful way. By that I mean that the exported data won't be useful at all.

If I close the query, I will loose valuable information.

How can I save this data in a way that I can continue with my work later?

Edit: I also know (and actually did it) that I can click each execution plan and save it as a file to analyse later). But I must export the rest of the data to excel,then each query plan manually and name the files by some kind of convention so I can match the query plan with the rest of the information... kinda lame.

Comment: You can't run the query again?  Also, you can save the query_plan and import it into something like SQLSentry for further analysis.

Comment: You can right click on the graphical queryplan and save as .sqlplan. You can open these files in SSMS and they will open as a standalone graphical plan.

Comment: @TTeeple the query is about cached execution plans in a moment or performance problems. Won't give me the same data if I run it now

Comment: @SteveFord Yes I know, But I have to save one at a time. I actually did it because it was important information.But then you have to manually "match" (ex: via file name convention) the plan information with each row with the rest of the data.